# What is the gradlew task assembleAndroidTest and what are the Test applications in Android?

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I've been coding in React-Native for a while and when I need to I write some native Android code as well. However, I had not seen this gradle task until I started using a library which used this particular gradle task.

That library is an end-to-end testing library (detox), and it uses this command `"cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd .."` to build the android `.apk` that will be used in the automated e2e test. Actually it builds two apks, the debug one and the AndroidTest one, but I don't know where the latter comes from or where it's configured or where the docs are about this.

I searched for an hour and did not find anything other than this very short description:
`assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.`

What are the Test applications?

Also, what is `-DtestBuildType=debug`?

Comment: Very good question. When i remove the command the detox tests run.

Answer (score 19):

When you run UI tests (also called instrumented tests) there are two apks that are built. One is your application's apk, the apk that you're probably familiar with, and a second apk that has all of the UI tests in it. When you run the test, both apks are uploaded to the device. `assembleAndroidTest` is the gradle command to build the second test apk. By default `assembleAndroidTest` will build the test apk with the debug build type. You can change the build type by adding this to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
  testBuildType "release"
  ..
```

What Detox is doing with the parameter `-DtestBuildType=debug` is taking this one step further and allowing you to dynamically specify the test apk build type through the gradle task. They do this by adding this to their build.gradle file:

```
testBuildType System.getProperty('testBuildType', 'debug')
```

One potential reason you might want to do this, is if you want to run your tests on a release build type in order to make sure that the tests still pass with proguard. So it would look like:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd .."
```